# iOS distribution certification conversion to p12 format

Tags: ios, apache-flex, certificate

I have a distribution certificate in iOS portal created previously for a project. Now I want to use this certificate for another project. But, I have lost its private key in Keychain. Is there a way I can convert distribution certificate to p12 format without private key? I dont want to delete and recreate the distribution file, as I suspect, it would impact my existing application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recreating your certificate does not impact any live apps. They continue to work. You will only need to recreate mobileprovisions to use the new cert when you use it again.

I am not sure if it impacts adhoc distributions, but I think it doesn't, at least not the ones which are already installed.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but we dont want to take any risk in revoking  the existing certificate as it is a company app and is live on our customers devices. Could you please provide any apple link which confirms that revoking this distribution certificate will not impact the existing apps. Thanks again for your reply.

Comment: I don't think its anywhere in the docs. But our clients have App Store mobprovs which use certs that have expired or been revoked and their apps haven't been affected. You can always contact Apple and confirm with them.

Comment: I posted the same question in apple developer community too, but got no answer yet. How could I confirm with Apple?

Comment: Try contacting Apple support instead of posting to the devforums - https://developer.apple.com/contact/ or https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/wa/jumpTo?page=contactUs